# Configuration for Spring stomp multi-application server

Tags: java, spring, websocket, cluster-computing, stomp

I'm developing a realtime notification system in Spring 4 by using a build-in Message Broker, and STOMP over WebSocket.

I would like to handle a case when there is a multi-application server and user destination is unresolved (because user is connected to another server). Spring docs claim there is a solution:

> In a multi-application server scenario a user destination may remain
>   unresolved because the user is connected to a different server. In
>   such cases you can configure a destination to broadcast unresolved
>   messages to so that other servers have a chance to try. This can be
>   done through the userDestinationBroadcast property of the
>   MessageBrokerRegistry in Java config and the
>   user-destination-broadcast attribute of the message-broker element in
>   XML.

But there is no example of such configuration. How can I set servers to recieve these messages and authentification parameters for system channel?

Answer (score 5):

When dealing with multi-node applications using WebSockets over STOMP you must configure and use an external STOMP Broker (such as RabbitMQ) so that different application instances can communicate each other. Are you already doing it, right?

In order to configure the `userDestinationBroadcast` and the `userRegistryBroadcast` just assign a destination name to them. When the application starts and the system TCP connection between the app and the broker is established, these destinations will be automatically created and everything will work fine and transparently.

I've coded a Web Chat app using Spring WebSockets, RabbitMQ and much more and its configuration is [available here](https://github.com/jorgeacetozi/ebook-chat-app-spring-websocket-cassandra-redis-rabbitmq/blob/master/ebook-chat/src/main/java/br/com/jorgeacetozi/ebookChat/configuration/WebSocketConfigSpringSession.java).

I hope this helps.

Comment: What happens if there is a message, and the client logged off? Is there a way to know that all servers can't locate the user, and thus the user didn't get the message?

Comment: @Jorge This is great direction, Thank you. I am stuck on a project, I need to send all the message to only to particular room from broker. How can that be achived ?